# SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error while using npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I run npm install , I get an error

Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I used to get this error. Try following steps.

Steps to be followed to overcome this error:

1)  Run these three commands in a sequence.

- npm config set strict-ssl false
- npm update npm –g
- npm config set strict-ssl true

2)  Set properties proxy and https-proxy in the npm config using these commands:

- npm config set proxy=“http://"proxy-name":8080”
- npm config set https-proxy=“http://"proxy-name":8080”

Then try installing your packages using commands you tried.

Hope this helps.