# Possibly unhandled SequelizeConnectionError: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Tags: node.js, ssl, mariadb

1. When I make call from node server to mariadb secured with ssl from MySQL command it works - that means certificates are correct
2. When I make SSL connection using node-MySQL I am able to make connection
3. However, when I use sequelize to make connection, it gives error 
   Possibly unhandled SequelizeConnectionError: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN 
   sequelize version 2.0.4 
   I tried the following but did not help -
   [SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error while using npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669510/self-signed-cert-in-chain-error-while-using-npm-install) 
   Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?