# NPM self_signed_cert_in_chain

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I am having issues getting NPM to install properly.  I have tried stepping through the instructions on several of the posts here on stack overflow, specifically from this thread:
[SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error while using npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669510/self-signed-cert-in-chain-error-while-using-npm-install)

Also I have tried going through the documentation on NPM's site:
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/78165272245/more-help-with-self-signed-cert-in-chain-and-npm.html

I am still receiving the error everytime I try to install.  please advise.

Comment: What is the actual error that you are receiving.

Comment: The link to the (now archived) npm blog is missing some hyphens: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/78165272245/more-help-with-self-signed-cert-in-chain-and-npm.html

Answer (score 141):

If you're behind the corporate proxy (which uses e.g. [*Blue Coat*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/135378/11825)), you should use http instead of https for repository addresses, e.g.

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

<sup>See: [Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN while using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796030/55075).</sup>

---

You can also import failing self-certificate into your system and mark as trusted, or temporary disable SSL validation while installing packages (quick, but not recommended method):

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

<sup>See: [Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN while using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9631045/55075).</sup>

---

The recommended way (and more painful) is just to point to the right certificate file, e.g.

```
npm config set cafile "<path to your certificate file>"
```

<sup>See: [How to fix SSL certificate error when running Npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30341389/55075).</sup>

Comment: I'm a corporate user, on OSX I found the relevant cert in the "Keychain Access" application, under the "System" keychain, in the "Certificates" category. I found one with the name "RootCA" in it, right click, export, choose the pem file format. Use that file as the cafile in this answer.

Comment: You can also identify the certificate with wget: `wget https://registry.npmjs.org/express`, yielding something like `cannot verify registry.npmjs.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=HTTPS Proxy CA,OU=…`.

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:

```
$ export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
$ npm install
```

Comment: This works, but this defeats the goal of using TLS at all. It's not recommended or even bad practice. Check this https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5258

Answer (score 11):

I know this question has been posted a few years ago. Since it still pops up at the top results on Google, I would like to share my proper and secure solution for this problem.

### **Solution for one Authority Root certificate**

I would like to advise everyone to make sure to keep your connection secured by using the https registry. Also, stop disabling strict-ssl. Many are missing the point here and go for a quick fix instead of the right solution.

You'll have to add your `.pem` certificate to the `.npmrc` file (npm config). When you just need to add **one certificate** use the following:

```
npm config set cafile /path/to/cert.pem
```

### **Solution for multiple Authority Root certificates**

When your company uses **multiple certificates** (like mine) you'll first need to combine the certificates to one `.pem` by entering the following command in your terminal:

```
cat cert1.pem cert2.pem > cert_combined.pem
```

Then make sure to point the right `.pem` file in your `.npmrc`

```
npm config set cafile /path/to/cert_combined.pem
```

Forget the solutions other people mention like `ca[]="..."` and `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`. This solution is tested and verified within a company that uses multiple Authority Root certificates using node v16.13.0 and npm v8.3.0.

Comment: Hi @Groenhout how do I find which certificate I should export from the mac keychain. I have more than 50 certificates. Does node uses any specific certificate that I can export in pem format and add it to npm config?

Comment: Hi @ParikTiwari, the following link will probably provide you with the information you’ll need. If not, let me know. Make sure to use de Root CA. https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details-in-every-browser

Comment: @M.Groenhout regarding the last paragraph of your answer to forget about ca[] and such... why should we forget that? I have a clue why, but not sure (think CA's are not bundled anymore with npm but were in the past?).

Comment: @M.Groenhout thank you! I've spent two days in `node-gyp` hell trying to figure out this self-signed cert in keychain issue I've had, and this is the answer that finally got everything working properly :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this command below and it could work fine:

> npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"